# What is wrong with my Arduino 7-segment display code?

Tags: arduino, software

I am trying to make some Arduino code count on a 7 segment display. I have the wiring all right but this code will not delay one second and go to next function. Any ideas?

```
/*
  Blink
  Turns on an LED on for one second, then off for one second, repeatedly.
  This example code is in the public domain.
 */

void setup() {                
  // initialize the digital pin as an output.
  // Pin 13 has an LED connected on most Arduino boards:
  pinMode(3,OUTPUT);    pinMode(4,OUTPUT);    pinMode(5,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(6,OUTPUT);    pinMode(7,OUTPUT);    pinMode(8,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(9,OUTPUT); 
}   

void n0() {
  digitalWrite(3,LOW);  digitalWrite(4,LOW);  digitalWrite(5,LOW);
  digitalWrite(6,LOW);  digitalWrite(7,LOW);  digitalWrite(8,LOW);
  digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
}

void ndash() {
  digitalWrite(3,HIGH); digitalWrite(4,HIGH); digitalWrite(5,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(6,HIGH); digitalWrite(7,HIGH); digitalWrite(8,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(9,LOW);
}

void loop() {
  n0();
  delay(1000);
  ndash();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your symptoms correctly, you need a second delay.

Here's what the code looks like if you executed the loop a few times:

```
  n0();
  delay(1000);
  ndash();
  n0();
  delay(1000);
  ndash();
  n0();
  delay(1000);
  ndash();
  n0();
  delay(1000);
  ndash();
```

ndash() is only displayed for however long it takes for n0() to execute, which is probably too fast to see.

Comment: The underlying C in Arduino is basically this: `int main() {setup(); for(;;) {loop();}}`